# quantmod difficulty loading data in correct format

Tags: quantmod

I am very new to R, I watched a youtube video to do various time series analysis, but it downloaded data from yahoo - my data is in Excel.  I wanted to follow the same analysis, but with data from an excel.csv file.  I spent two days finding out that the date must be in USA style.  Now I am stuck again on a basic step - loading the data so it can be analysed - this seems to be the biggest hurdle with R.  Please can someone give me some guidance on why the command shown below does not do the returns for the complete column set.  I tried the zoo format, but it didn't work, then I tried xts and it worked partially. I suspect the original import from excel is the major problem. Can I get some guidance please

```
> AllPrices <- as.zoo(AllPrices)
> head(AllPrices)
             Index1   Index2   Index3  Index4   Index5   Index6   Index7   Index8   Index9 Index10

> AllRets <- dailyReturn(AllPrices)
Error in NextMethod("[<-") : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
> AllPrices<- as.xts(AllPrices)
> AllRets <- dailyReturn(AllPrices)
> head(AllRets)
           daily.returns
2012-11-06  0.000000e+00
2012-11-07 -2.220249e-02
2012-11-08  1.379504e-05
2012-11-09  2.781961e-04
2012-11-12 -2.411128e-03
2012-11-13  7.932869e-03
```

Comment: Sorry that did not paste as I thought, this is my first post

Comment: Sorry, that did not paste as I thought, this is my first post.  I wanted to load an excel CSV file with 10 headings (prices) for use with the package quantmod.  Then calculate returns and various risk attributes.  This seems to be quite a challenge.  I tried loading the columns one at a time in separate files, which worked ok, but then I could not get them to merge, so I tried loading them in one file, with a worse outcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your data using the `readr` package.

`library(readr)`

Then, look at the documentation by running `?read_csv` in the console.

I recommend reading in your data this way. Specify the column types. For instance, if your first column is the date, read it in as a character "c" and if your other columns are numeric use "n".

```
data <- read_csv('YOUR_DATA.csv', col_types = "cnnnnn") # date in left column, 5 numeric columns
data$Dates <- as.Date(data$Dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d") # make the dates column a date class (you need to update "Dates" to be your column name for the Dates column, you may need to change the format
data <- as.data.frame(data) # turn the result into a dataframe
data <- xts(data[,-1], order.by = XAU[,1]) # then make an xts, data is everything but the date column, order.by is the date column
```

Comment: Thank you Jared for responding, I will try that.